# docker react app shuts down after compose

Tags: reactjs, docker, npm

I've got a problem with my react app on docker.

If I want to run my react app in docker i use:

```
docker run -dit app .
```

Without its parameters it shuts down immediately after run.

I have the same problem when I use docker compose:

```
randevou-react-client_1  | ℹ ｢wds｣: Project is running at http://172.18.0.4/
randevou-react-client_1  | ℹ ｢wds｣: webpack output is served from 
randevou-react-client_1  | ℹ ｢wds｣: Content not from webpack is served from /usr/src/app/public
randevou-react-client_1  | ℹ ｢wds｣: 404s will fallback to /
randevou-react-client_1  | Starting the development server...
randevou-react-client_1  | 
repo_randevou-react-client_1 exited with code 0
```

My docker-compose file:

```
version: "3"

services:
    randevou-rest-backend:
        build: "./randevou_netCore"
        ports:
            - "7777:7777"
    randevou-react-client:
        build: "./RandevouReact"
        ports:
            - "8001:3000"
              # randevou-angular-client:
              #        build: "./RandevouAngularClient"
              #        ports:
              #            - "8002:4200"
    randevou-mvc-client:
        build: "./RandevouMVC/RandevouClientMVC"
        ports:
        - "8003:8888"
```

Other services are running properly...

My package.json (from react app):

```
 "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
```

My Dockerfile for react app :

```
# base image
FROM node:10

# set working directory
RUN mkdir -p /usr/src/app
WORKDIR /usr/src/app

# add `/app/node_modules/.bin` to $PATH
ENV PATH /app/node_modules/.bin:$PATH

# install and cache app dependencies
COPY package.json ./package.json

RUN npm cache clean --force
RUN npm install --silent
RUN npm install react-scripts@3.4.0 -g --silent
COPY . .

EXPOSE 3000
# start app
CMD ["npm", "start"]
```

What did I do wrong?

Comment: If you use `react-scripts` version `3.4.1`, it's still an [open issue](https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/issues/8688).

Comment: thanks dude, it works!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

stdin_open: true

do the trick

```
 randevou-react-client:
        build: "./RandevouReact"
        stdin_open: true
        ports:
            - "8001:3000"
```